# How to find the quadratic equation using 2 given solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Find the quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, Such that $a=1$ and the solutions are:

$3(\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})), 2(\cos(\frac{5\pi}{6}) + i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6}))$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions that merely copy the statement of a problem are not generally welcomed. Can you add some information about what is causing you trouble?

Comment: I know I have to use the solutions to find the equation, but I don't know how to go about doing that. I believe the first step is to simplify the solutions individually, but I have no idea what to do after that.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

How about this quadratic equation: $$\left[x-3\left\{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right\}\right]\cdot \left[x-2\left\{\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)\right\}\right]$$

Can you simplify this?

Comment: Well that's the issue, I don't understand this problem at all.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you know and what you don't? It will help us to answer your problem in a better way.

Comment: I know what the quadratic equation is and I know that somehow, the 2 solutions that I am given are to be used to solve FOR the equation in the form of ax^2 + bx + c = 0. we already know a=1 but I don't know how to get the b and c values

Comment: Check this ......http://www.math-only-math.com/relation-between-roots-and-coefficients-of-a-quadratic-equation.html ... it will help you surely...

Comment: It didn't really help. I need a step by step with this particular problem. I have been trying for the past 3 hours to get it and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You know that a quadratic polynomial can be represented as the product of its roots $p(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$ where $ a,b $ are the roots. Since you are given the roots; simply go ahead and reconstruct the quadratic. In this case however $b$ and $c$ may turn out to be complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If $x = x_0$ and $x= x_1$ are the two solutions to $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ and $a = 1$ then

$ax^2 + bx + c = (x-x_0)(x-x_1) = x^2 + (-x_0 + x_1)x + x_0x_1 = 0$

And $a = 1$ $b = (-x_0 + x_1)$ and c= $(x_0x_1)$.

So if $x_0 = 3(\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}))$ and $x_1 = 2(\cos(\frac{5\pi}{6}) + i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6}))$

Then $b = -3(\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}))- 2(\cos(\frac{5\pi}{6}) + i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6}))$ and $c = 3(\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}))* 2(\cos(\frac{5\pi}{6}) + i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6}))$

Comment: Okay, so I simplified b and c, is that the answer? Or is there still another step?

Comment: Simplifying them out should do it.  You should probably double check and see if you made any error but plugging those answers back into your quadratic equation and seeing if you get 0.  It might be easier to write the 3(cos(pi/3) + i sin(pi/3)) as $3e^{\frac{\pi}3 i}$ etc.